# Generators of the symplectic subgroup $\Gamma^g(1,2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, modular-forms, siegel-modular-forms

Let $\mathbb{A}^{m\times n}$ denote the set of all $m \times n$ matrices with entries in the set $\mathbb{A}$. For a matrix $M$ we let ${^tM}$ denote its transpose, and $M^{-1}$ its inverse, if it is invertible. We denote the $r \times r$ identity matrix by $I_r$.

We define the symplectic modular group of degree $g$ by
$$\Gamma^g:=\text{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})= \left\{ M \in \mathbb{Z}^{2g \times 2g} \mid {^tM}JM = J \right\} ,
J = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
{0} & {I_g}\\
{-I_g} & {0}
\end{smallmatrix}
\right).
$$

We define the following subgroup
$$\Gamma^g(1,2):= \left\{ M =
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
{A} & {B}\\
{C} & {D}
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\in \Gamma^g \mid {^tA}C,  {^tB}D \text{ have even diagonals} \right\}.$$

Mumford (see Appendix to Chapter 2 Section 5 of Tata Lectures on Theta I) gives the following generators for $\Gamma^g(1,2)$:
$$J, \quad
\left\{ 
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
{A} & {0}\\
{0} & {^tA^{-1}}
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\mid A \in \text{GL}(g, \mathbb{Z}) \right\},
\quad
\left\{ 
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}
{I_g} & {B}\\
{0} & {I_g}
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\mid B \text{ is symmetric, integral and has even diagonal}  \right\}.$$

Consider the matrix
$$E=
 %\left(
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
%\right)
\in \Gamma^2(1,2).$$
Can anyone tell me how $E$ can be expressed in terms of Mumford's generators?